# Is there a tool or framework to Generate a CRUD UI in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, crud

I am looking for a tool/framework to (automatically) generate a Swing user interface to perform CRUD operations on an underlying database.

I would also like to configure the database fields that should be exposed.  Something like django (via [modelforms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms)) or ruby on rails features, but in a Java desktop environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans does seem like an obvious answer.  These guys make a NetBeans plugin that does just that:
http://www.morelisland.com/java_services/netbeans_tutorial/midbmetadata_se.htm

I've heard jgoodies does something similar:
http://www.jgoodies.com/products/index.html

And more specifically their sub-project, Binding:
https://binding.dev.java.net/

I know less about the SwingLabs databinding project, but it looks worth looking into:
https://databinding.dev.java.net/

Comment: Thank you, lets see if other people send alternative approaches before setting your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at tools like:

MetaWidget http://www.metawidget.org/

[Apache Isis](http://isis.apache.org/)

They generate UI's "on-the-fly" but allow you to customise the UI when necessary.

Much better than code generation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Netbeans (latest). I guess it's far from Django (haven't tried it, but as far as I understand it is kind of rails/symfony-like,)  but it does reverse engineer the database and give you a basic application including a master/detail view.

Answer (score 0):

You may use hibernate to generate mapping and Djf to view these mappings on Swing components.  Desktop Java Forms is located here: https://github.com/smart-flex/Djf

But, unfortunately it is non fully automated way of generating a Swing user interface to perform CRUD operations.