# Simple java scaffolding-like CRUD generator

Tags: java, swing, crud, scaffolding

Is there any simple, lightweight crud form generator for swing in java?

I have a desktop application that uses spring+hibernate and I am only missing a bunch of gui panels allowing to edit some database entities. Pretty straightforward attribute-editable forms, so I though there has to be some tool to automate the process. I don't need any DAO/pojo/bean/controller/service generation.

I've read a bit about this in other questions but all the solutions seem to involve installing a whole framework and the generation of complex non-standard java code. I just want plain swing panels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CRUD generator utility in Java(any framework) like Scaffolding in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414583/is-there-a-crud-generator-utility-in-javaany-framework-like-scaffolding-in-rai)

Comment: Not a duplicate because that question was about web frameworks and this is about desktop/swing.

Comment: There are far too many options available; you're going to have to narrow things down a bit.  There are a number of code-generators which will start with your schema, and generate whole apps by dragging tables from the database to a display panel (see MyEclipse and NetBeans).  You can just build the panels very quickly with NetBeans, Matisse in Eclipse, and a plethora of commercial tools. I suggest you clarify exactly what you want done in your own mind, then google.

Comment: I just want a tool that, provided with a DB model, automatically generates panels/forms with the needed GUI elements. I.e. a checkbox for boolean attributes, a combo for object attributes, a textfield for string attributes... I guess those you mentioned do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359993/is-there-a-tool-or-framework-to-generate-a-crud-ui-in-swing

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is anything like you are looking for. However, why not create a web application with Grails (or Rails, or whatever your favorite web framework is) that contains web services that do the DB work and then just call the web services from within your desktop app?

Comment: because what I want done is the GUI itself, and my app is a desktop application. i.e. I need the forms in swing.

Comment: You can still have your forms in Swing but be calling web services behind the scenes. If your DB is on a remote server (i.e. you aren't storing in a local DB on the user's desktop) then using web services behind the scenes is the way to go.